# How can I graphically visualize numerical data that I receive through a serial port?

Tags: python, user-interface, oscilloscope

I am trying to design an application in python to be able to read the data sent by a PIC microcontroller, for this I will use a UART-To-RS232 converter and then a RS232-To-USB converter to be able to receive the data on my computer, the PIC sends the voltage values ​​of an AC signal and my application should be able to display these data on a graph, similar to the Arduino IDE serial plotter, but I want to get the effect of an oscilloscope, that is, to be able to see the graph as if it were the screen of a oscilloscope, being able to modify the time scale and amplitude of the signal that I am viewing and all those things that an oscilloscope does haha, how could I achieve this effect or what algorithms should I use to do this? I hope you can help me.

Regards.

Comment: A fairly simple option might be to throw the data into **InfluxDB** and then use **Grafana** to display it.

Comment: Or Python `matplotlib` can do animated plots...

Comment: `pygame` should be able to do this too, see https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/